# Django try/except on DoesNotExist still throws it

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling with a `DoesNotExist` error on my application. The point is that I don't really understand why this error is thrown as I already handle it:

```
import socket

from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db import Models

class MyClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=socket.gethostname(), unique=True)
    @staticmethod
    def update_some_list(some_list):
        for some_item in some_list:
            try:
                MyClass.objects.get(name=some_item)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:  # I also tried with MyClass.DoesNotExist
                MyClass.objects.create(name=some_item)
```

The point here is that, when I run into this code, I have some "module-level" DoesNotExist that is thrown away, as if this try/except block is never hit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/backend/shared/models.py", line 201, in update_some_list
    MyClass.objects.get(name=some_item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
shared.models.DoesNotExist: MyClass matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Did you try to catch a general error in except and print something out just to see if django generally jumps into the except clause?

Comment: It looks as if the exception is not a Django error, but an exception in `shared.models`?

Comment: Can you make a blanket exception, and print `print(type(e).__qualname__)`.

Comment: You are catching the `django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist` while the raised one is a `shared.models.DoesNotExist`.

Comment: Yup, the problem is that I didn't implemented a shared.models.DoesNotExist. I guess it has something to do with my `@staticmethod`, maybe? Anyway, I re-deployed a new debugging version containing a mix of both of your proposals, a `catch Error as e` and `print(type(e).__qualname__)` did not output anything

Comment: Even when using the decorator `@staticmethod` you still have to define a method with `def`. Therefore it should be `def update_some_list(some_list)`. Is it just a typo in the example?

Comment: Indeed, sorry about that, I fixed the typo and thanks for this

Comment: So after working with the logging class it turns out that with `ObjectDoesNotExist` the Error is catched, and the code runs now ok, working with `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [QuerySet.get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create), which shall eliminate the problem above.

```
MyClass.objects.get_or_create(name=some_item)
```

Also, please note, that if you access class inside the [@staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) it makes sense to update it to be [@classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod). Also, in the question you are having:

```
from django.db import Models
```

instead of 
    from django.db import models

Comment: Sorry, I accepted the answer too quickly. I now have the same error but in function  `get_or_create`, still wondering what's happening in there

Comment: @Yoiro strange. You can handle both exceptions at the same time: `except (ObjectDoesNotExist, MyClass.DoesNotExist)`

Comment: The weirdest part in all of this is that it throws a `shared.models.DoesNotExist`, which is my module name and not my class so... I really don't understand this error. Now I've corrected some other errors (related to external API calls) and this one doesn't show anymore, so... Dunno, Python :D